# How to pass struct as a parameter to a function

Tags: json, go, struct, types, slice

How can I do something Like this?

I am trying to pass a `struct` as a parameter to function in Go.

```
func handleEntityProperties(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    const sliceSize = 100
    var entityProperties struct {
        Instance string `json:"instance"`
        Entities []struct {
            Id         string            `json:"id"`
            Properties map[string]string `json:"properties"`
            Type       string            `json:"type"`
        } `json:"entities"`
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if !json.Valid([]byte(body)) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "invalid json")
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &entityProperties)

    sendData(entityProperties.Entities[0:100])

    return
}

func sendData(entities struct) {
    log.Println("Doing things with entities ", entities)
}
```

as you can see in code I am trying to send first 100 elements of `entityProperties.Entities` `struct` to a `sendData`. I know this is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just declare your type outside of the functions:

```
type entity struct {
    Id         string            `json:"id"`
    Properties map[string]string `json:"properties"`
    Type       string            `json:"type"`
}
```

And reuse it in `handleEntityProperties()` and in the signature of `sendData()`:

```
func handleEntityProperties(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    const sliceSize = 100
    var entityProperties struct {
        Instance string   `json:"instance"`
        Entities []entity `json:"entities"`
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if !json.Valid([]byte(body)) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "invalid json")
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &entityProperties)

    sendData(entityProperties.Entities[0:sliceSize])

    return
}

func sendData(entities []entity) {
    log.Println("Doing things with entities ", entities)
}
```

Also note that there is no guarantee that the client will send at least 100 entities, so you should check that else the slicing expression might result in a runtime panic:

```
max := 100
if len(entityProperties.Entities) < max {
    max = len(entityProperties.Entities)
}
sendData(entityProperties.Entities[:max])
```

Also that check for invalid JSON is unnecessary: if the JSON is invalid, [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) will report a (non-`nil`) error and you'll know it.

Going further, you don't even have to read the complete body into memory (into a byte slice), you may use [`json.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) to read from it directly (without the intermediate memory buffer) like this:

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
if err := dec.Decode(&entityProperties); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

And the final `return` statement is also unnecessary.

So an improved version may look like this:

```
func handleEntityProperties(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var entityProperties struct {
        Instance string   `json:"instance"`
        Entities []entity `json:"entities"`
    }

    dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    if err := dec.Decode(&entityProperties); err != nil {
        // handle error
        http.Error(w, "invalid json", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    max := 100
    if len(entityProperties.Entities) < max {
        max = len(entityProperties.Entities)
    }
    sendData(entityProperties.Entities[:max])
}
```